# How can I view the differences between commits filtered by contributors on GitHub?

Tags: github

I'm not sure if GitHub questions are off-topic, but I'll take the chance.

- Day 1 - I created a new branch called `feature` and added changes.
- Day 2 - I ran `git pull origin master`
- Day 3 - I created a PR and I merged to `master`
- Day 4 - I continued working on branch `feature` and again, I added some changes.
- Day 5 - ... and so on...

*While I wrote the code, another contributor wrote with me on the same branch (`feature`)).*

I and another contributor wanted to review our work from the first commit to last. In order to do so, I navigated to:

```
https://github.com/<organization>/<repo>/compare/<base>...<target>

  base = our initial commit
  target = our last commit
```

Well, it didn't go quite as planned. We noticed that a lot of the changes were not made by us, but by different contributors (11 in fact):

[image]

I get that it happened because a lot of commits that weren't written by us has been made between `base...target`. So I want to know, is there a way I can filter the commits by specific contributors? or, is there any other way we could see only our changes?

Comment: Have you tried something like `git shortlog --author john.doe` ?

Comment: Never heard of it. I guess ur talking about CLI commands. I want it to be shown on GitHub

Comment: Ok I remove the `git` tag

Comment: It seems to me it does not help using an author filter in browser address bar like `https://github.com/<organization>/<repo>/compare/<base>...<target>?author=someone`.  I have not use github for teams yet, not sure that service has something to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For
You can filter, if your github repo is

```
https://github.com/name/repo/
```

you can filter by author on a specific branch

```
https://github.com/name/repo/commits/feature?author=john.doe
```

A real example:

https://github.com/utix/util-linux/commits/cal_column?author=karelzak

https://github.com/utix/util-linux/commits/cal_column

Answer (score 0):

Click on **"Commits 97"** (on your picture) and you will see all commits from this GitHub project. You can also see all users who have ever changed your project. If you then click on a user name, all commits of this user are displayed in this project. So you can click on your username and the other contributor's username, and you'll see all the commits from the selected user both times.
I hope you come out with my explanation